# DOMDocument - set valid id for getElementById

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to get an element by id. But I am not successful. Why is the following not able to find the element with my given id?

I have set up a test case:

```
<?php

$m_oDom = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );
$m_oDom->formatOutput = true;
$m_oDom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$m_oDom->validateOnParse = true;

$strId = "abc";

$oElement = $m_oDom->createElement( 'div' );    

$oAttribute = $oElement->setAttribute( 'id', $strId );

$oElement->setIdAttribute( 'id', false ); // tried also without this

$oElement->appendChild( $oAttribute );

// $oAttribute = $oElement->getAttributeNode( 'id' );

$b = $oAttribute->isId();

if( $b ) {
   echo "true";   
} else {
   echo "false"; // says false
}

$oElement = $m_oDom->getElementById( $strId );

if( $oElement ) {
   echo "element";   
} else {
   echo "false"; // says false
}

?>
```

Comment: _“Why is the following not able to find the element with my given id?”_ – because you are not setting an actual id, you are just creating an attribute that happens to have the name “id”. Please read the manual on `setIdAttribute` and `getElementById`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying something like this:

```
$oElement = $m_oDom->createElement( 'div' );    

$oAttribute = $oElement->setAttribute( 'id', $strId );

$oElement->setIdAttribute( 'id', true ); // tried also without this

$m_oDom->appendChild( $oElement );
```

It returns true and element output to me.

Comment: Argh!! Thanks man, I misread the docs on `setIdAttribute`. Changing `false` to `true` did it of course...